# Access variable in added movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scope

I'm in class file right now and made a new movie clip using the linkage name

```
var mc = new ExampleLinkageName();
addChild(mc);
```

all good, I can see `mc` on the stage. In the `ExampleLinkageName` movieclip, I have a variable defined in it (on the physical timeline) called `test`.

In my class, I try `trace(mc.test)` and I get `null`. Any idea how I can read that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, but the variable has not been created (the first frame actions has not executed) when you try to access it. If you (for debug purpose) try to access `mc.test` in the next frame of your timeline you will get the correct variable value. Or add an ENTER_FRAME EventListener to the created Movieclip like this:

```
var mc : Symbol1 = new Symbol1();
mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initHandler);
addChild(mc);

function initHandler(event : Event) : void
{
    trace(mc.test);
    mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initHandler);
}
```

Comment: Ah! Great fix sir. I had to tweak it just a hair though. In the initHandler method, I did `if (mc.test) ... removeEF`. If I let it run just once it wouldn't have worked.